# How to embed an iFrame into QT?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, iframe, desktop-application

I am using Qt with c++ to create a desktop application and I have to embed an iFrame into my application but I am not pretty sure if it is going to work. The iFrame has an application writen in JavaScript that has to communicate with the GUI writen in c++ over Qt.

I know how to do it on Windows using MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes), as it's explained in [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2352/JavaScript-call-from-C) but I want my application to be cross-platform.

As far as I remember, On Windows I was using the classes IWebBrowser or IHTMLDocument that do something like embedding an Internet explorer navigator into my desktop application. I would like to do the same but cross-platform.

I also would like to know what kind of navigator is going to be embedded (Chromium or Firefox?).

Also I am not just tied to Qt, any other cross-platform tool that allows me to do what I explained would be useful, and better if it is free software.

Any answer that orients me in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt 5, you may want to use the [Qt WebEngine module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-index.html) which

> provides functionality for rendering regions of dynamic web content.

Basically, you have Chromium at your disposal to be embedded in both qml or [widgets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-overview.html#embedding-web-content-into-widget-based-applications) applications.

Moreover, javascript (and html) can interact with the Qt API (both c++ and QML)  through the [WebChannel module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html).